# ImportError: cannot import name plots. In UBUNTU and WINDOWS

Tags: python, python-2.7, compiler-errors, importerror

I am working on this [tutorial](https://getdist.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plot_gallery.html).

it has one line as the following:

```
from getdist import plots, MCSamples
```

but python send error which:

```
ImportError: cannot import name plots
```

what should I do? I need it, but it sends this error.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install the *getdist* module prior to working on the tutorial?

Comment: @CristiFati yes, using `sudo pip install getdist` they said in their introduction in website. and I give: `Requirement already satisfied: getdist in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Answer (score 0):

The name of file was similar to the modules.

`getdist.py`!!!
I changed it to `gd.py` and everything is ok.